# Fill a portion of canvas path with different color

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, progress-bar

I have already made a green path in canvas that looks like this:

[image: already made path]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/2/125/2prKT5FY/deletemestackoverflow.png))</sub>

I had to use 4 *lineTo()* and 4 *quadraticCurveTo()* functions. I want to build somekind of progress bar that would look like this:

[image: the goal]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/2m/BL/1Spxusi3/deleteme2stackoverflow.png))</sub>

Are there any easy solutions to this in canvas? My goal is to have a JavaScript function that would update the canvas shape based on progress percentage. I know I could just make another blue coloured shape after the green one but how exactly would I calculate the appropriate length of it? Any help much appreciated:)

Comment: You could use the same code as for the green border and just `clip` the purple border.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327892/canvas-rectangle-with-rounded-corners-as-a-progress-bar/16330390#16330390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rounded rectangle consists of 9 subpaths:

1. The right half of the upper border,
2. The top right corner,
3. The right-hand border,
4. The bottom right corner,
5. The lower border,
6. The bottom left corner,
7. The left-hand border,
8. The upper right corner, and
9. The left half of the upper border.

Let *w* be the rectangle's width, *h* the rectangle's height and *r* the border radius.

The total length of the path is about*:

Length = (w - 2r)*2 + (h -2r)*2 + 2πr

Multiplying this length by a percentage gives you a sublength, which is the length to give the blue path. Each of your rectangle's subpaths has the following length:

- 1, 9: (w-2r)/2
- 2, 4, 6, 8: πr/2
- 3, 7: (h-2r)
- 5: (w-2r)

Now, using the sublength, iterate through each subpath in the order given above. For each subpath:

- If the sublength is greater than or equal to the subpath's length, draw the whole subpath, and reduce
  the sublength by the subpath's length.
- Otherwise, draw part of the subpath according to the length. This will involve calculating a partial line or partial arc, which is relatively easy compared to calculating a more complicated path. Then stop drawing.

* I say "about" since you're using quadratic curves to approximate the arcs on the corners. By the way, you can use the `arc` method instead for those corners.

Comment: It works, thank you for the nice solution. I switched to arc methods and the corners look almost the same as they did with quadratic curves. Arc length is easier to calculate :)